# Remove closed editor windows from Ctrl-Tab switcher?

Tags: intellij-idea

Say I have the following files open in IntelliJ

```
Foo | Bar | CloseMe*
```

As you can see, `CloseMe` is currently open. If I close `CloseMe`, the editor switches to `Bar` and my tabs look like this:

```
Foo | Bar*
```

However, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> then `CloseMe` opens up again, instead of `Foo` as I would expect.

```
Foo | Bar | CloseMe*
```

Is there some way to remove closed files from the Switcher?

Answer (score 8):

This was annoying me beyond belief.

As far as I know, there is no way to change the functionality of Switcher (<kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>) from inside of IntelliJ.

To solve this problem I recommend using [TabSwitch plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/179) for IntelliJ. It cycles through open files only. After installing the plugin, assign the <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> keybind to Plug-ins -> TabSwitch -> Next tab and voilà, closed tabs don't interfere anymore.

On a side note, why would they change it that it would do identical thing with Recent Files (<kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>)? I see no logic behind this change... It's such a stupid change that I believe it is a bug.